# How to fetch asynchronous data with react hooks every 10 mins

Tags: reactjs, caching, axios, react-hooks, setinterval

I am trying to asynchronously fetch some data in react every 10 minutes. I attempted doing so with the code below. I printed out the data with `console.log(cases)` for debugging and saw that it remains stale, as with refreshing the page. It remains stale until I hard refresh the page with ctrl+f5. So it seems to be a caching issue, what would be the best approach to solve this? Thanks.

```js
const url = 'https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/all'
const [info,setInfo] = useState({})
const fetchData = async()=>{
        try{
            const {data :{cases,active,recovered,deaths,updated}} = await axios.get(url) 
            console.log(cases)
            setInfo({cases,active,recovered,deaths,updated})
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
}
useEffect( ()=>{
        const interval = setInterval(fetchData,600000)
        return ()=> clearInterval(interval)
},[])
```

Comment: As you're just logging `cases`, what if the `cases` don't change in 10 minutes. Check the other fields.

Comment: @RameshReddy I have tested with other fields, they remain the same on soft refresh, and gets updated on hard refresh. The problem doesn't seem to be unchanging data after the 10 min mark.

Comment: You can remove `setInfo` from the dependency array of the `useEffect` because it never changes